# Why recv() returns '0' bytes at all for-loop iterations except the first one?

Tags: http, sockets, recv

I'm writing a small networking program in C++. Among other things it has to download twitter profile pictures. I have a list (stl::vector) of URLs. And I think that my next step is to create for-loop and send GET messages through the socket and save the pictures to different png-files. The problem is when I send the very first message, receive the answer segments and save png-data all things seems to be fine. But right at the next iteration the same message, sent through the same socket, produces 0 received bytes by recv() function. I solved the problem by adding a socket creation code to the cycle body, but I'm a bit confused with the socket concepts. It looks like when I send the message, the socket should be closed and recreated again to send next message to the same server (in order to get next image). Is this a right way of socket's networking programming or it is possible to receive several HTTP response messages through the same socket?

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Here is the code with the loop where I create a socket.

```
    // Get links from xml.
    ...
    // Load images in cycle.
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<imageLinks.size(); i++)
    {
        // New socket is returned from serverConnect. Why do we need to create new at each iteration?
        string srvAddr = "207.123.60.126";
        int socketImg = serverConnect(srvAddr);
        // Create a message.
        ...
        string message = "GET " + relativePart;
                message += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        message += "Host: " + hostPart + "\r\n";
        message += "\r\n";
        // Send a message.
        BufferArray tempImgBuffer = sendMessage(sockImg, message, false);
        fstream pFile;
        string name;
        // Form the name.
        ...
        pFile.open(name.c_str(), ios::app | ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
        // Write the file contents.
        ...
        pFile.close();
        // Close the socket.
        close(sockImg);
    }
```

Comment: You should post relevant code. A large paragraph of text is not too useful.

Comment: I understand this. But the code is too large and I don't know what part of it to post here. I just wanted to ask about sockets implementation. Is it default behaviour to close the connection? Because I found it a bit strange. I could receive all the messages (all images) through the same socket. Why do i need to create it again for each image?

Comment: An important part of learning how to be a programmer is to figure out how to extract the essential parts of the code relevant to your problem. That's also how you figure out the answers, and that combined with understanding the other side of the interaction is how you avoid having to ask the question in the first place. In this case you should read the HTTP specs and think about how your code implements it. Oh, and @cnicutar's answer is likely the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other side is closing the connection. That's how `HTTP/1.0` works. You can:

- Make a different connection for each HTTP GET
- Use `HTTP/1.0` with the unofficial  `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- Use `HTTP/1.1`. In `HTTP 1.1` all connections are considered persistent unless declared otherwise.

Obligatory xkcd link **[Server Attention Span](http://xkcd.com/869/)**

**[Wiki HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)**

> The original version of HTTP
>   (HTTP/1.0) was revised in HTTP/1.1.
>   HTTP/1.0 uses a separate connection to
>   the same server for every
>   request-response transaction, while
>   HTTP/1.1 can reuse a connection
>   multiple times

Answer (score 3):

HTTP in its original form (HTTP 1.0) is indeed a "one request per connection" protocol. Once you get the response back, the other side has probably closed the connection. There were unofficial mechanisms added to some implementations to support multiple requests per connection, but they were not standardized.

[HTTP 1.1 turns this around](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). All connections are by default "persistent".

To use this, you need to add "HTTP/1.1" to the end of your request line. Instead of `GET http://someurl/`, do `GET http://someurl/ HTTP/1.1`. You'll also need to make sure you provide the "Host:" header when you do this.

Note well, however, that even some otherwise-compliant HTTP servers may not support persistent connections. Note also that the connection may in fact be dropped after very little delay, a certain number of requests, or just randomly. You *must* be prepared for this, and ready to re-connect and resume issuing your requests where you left off.

See also the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).